# Android - Getting NetworkOnMainThreadException for file download even though download is started in separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, networkonmainthread

I am a bit confused with threading on Android, basically I want to download video file, but I am getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

MY setup is as follows, I have a `VideoDownloader` class that is there only to download a video. Its main method looks like this:

`public void downloadVideoFile(Context context, String videoURL, String targetFileName)`
. This will open an http connection to the `videoURL` and save it to the file system using the `context`'s `openFileOutput` method and the `targetFileName` as the name for the file. Nothing to consider about multithreading yet.

Then I am implementing a `VideoDownloadTask` which looks as follows:

```
public class VideoDownloadTask extends Thread {

  private VideoDownloader videoDownloader;

  public VideoDownloadTask(VideoDownloader videoDownloader){
    this.videoDownloader = videoDownloader;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    videoDownloader.startDownload();
  }

  public void cancel(){
    Log.d(Constants.LOG, "DEBUG [" + getClass().getName() + "]: Cancel current downloaded in video downloader");
    videoDownloader.cancel();

  }
}
```

This class is supposed to start a video download in its own thread, given an instance of `VideoDownloader` during initialization.

Finally, in my activity I am executing the following method:

```
    private void initiateFileDownload() {

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String seriesName = intent.getStringExtra("seriesName");
      String amazonKey = intent.getStringExtra("amazonKey");
      String videoURL = intent.getStringExtra("videoURL");

      URIGenerator uriGenerator = new URIGenerator();
      String targetFilePath = uriGenerator.buildTargetFilePath(seriesName, amazonKey);
      Log.d(Constants.LOG, "DEBUG [" + getClass().getName() + "]: Initiate file download to file: " + targetFilePath);

      VideoDownloader videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(this, videoURL, targetFilePath);

      videoDownloadTask = new VideoDownloadTask(videoDownloader);
      videoDownloadTask.run();
    }
```

As I said in the beginning, this code throws a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, but I am wondering why, because according to my understanding I am executing the video download in a separate thread (in the `VideoDownloadTask`), or am I wrong and the fact that I *create* the instance of the `VideoDownloader` on the main thread is enough to also make it run its method on the main thread, no matter if I am giving it to a separate thread?

Can anyone help me improve this piece of code so that the download is going to work?

Comment: why dont you use `AsyncTask` instead of `Thread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `start()` to start a new thread. `run()` just runs the code in the current thread.

Comment: Great, it's working, thanks!! I am going to accept the answer ASAP :)